# Font Not displaying properly in ipad device

Tags: html, ipad, web

I am using Helvetica Italic New font for web page in ipad it works fine on browser in pc but it is not showing same on device.

font-family:"Helvetica Neu"
it is not displaying this font on device.

Answer (score 0):

Helvetica Neue should be available on iOS 5 devices, see [the official list of fonts](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4980?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) here. Did you spell the font name correctly?

Comment: i have written font name correctly in css file still it does not work

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant section of the css file in question.